# $.ajax success function won't show in the console when I do console.log(data);

Tags: jquery, ajax

In the $.ajax function I have the function for success like this:

```
success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
},
```

but when I use the $.ajax function, it won't show anything in the console. If I use the $.post function and THEN I console.log(data), it WILL show up in the console, however it won't work because I can't have processData: false in the $.post function.

This is my entire $.ajax function:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'post',
    type: 'POST',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: formData,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function() {}
});
```

Comment: is your target URL indeed called `post` ?

Comment: Are you sure it's going into the success callback?  Seems like it might be going into error.  Put an alert in your error to test.

Comment: In the Javascript console, there's a tab called Network. Open a browser, open the console and to go the Network tab in it, then open your page and run the code that calls your AJAX. Look for the call in the Network tab and see what happens. You can also add a `console.log()` to your `error` handler.

Comment: @karthikr yes, I'm using laravel and the post route is set to /user/post, and now I'm in /user. And drneel alright, I'll test that out.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly altering your code to run in jsfiddle, I don't see any problems (I get `Success! Object {}`):

```
var formData = {test: 'test'};

$.ajax({
    url: '/echo/json',
    type: 'POST',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: formData,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log('Success!', data);
    },
    error: function(e) {
        console.log('Error!', e);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zta6ugyw/

I suspect it's your URL. Watch Network tab in console to see if your server is returning a 404 or some other error.